# Restricting the range of values in a recursive function

Tags: functions

Hello I am relatively new to Mathematica and I have a problem regarding my model. I have the following function:

```
P[t_] := P[t] = P[t - 1] + a* (df[t - 1] + dc[t - 1]);
```

(`df` and `dc` are defined and not so important for this question.)

Now I want to restrict this function following the expression:

```
P[t]*(1-i) < P[t+1] < P[t]*(1+i)
```

`i` is supposed to go from 0 up to 0.13 for each period t.

For context, this function is supposed to represent prices in a market and I want to set up a price restriction.

Comment: Use `Clip` to restrict the next price: `P[t_] := P[t] = Clip[P[t-1] + a*(df[t-1] + dc[t-1]), {P[t-1]*(1-i), P[t-1]*(1+i)}];`

Comment: Also, instead of `i` use `ivals[[t+1]]` where `ivals = Subdivide[0.13, maxsteps - 1];`